MS Access Repaint/Recalc form?
I have a dynamic MS Access form that hides/shows some fields based on values in other fields.
I'm currently using field.Visible and field.Height to hide the fields, and close the gap. The visibility of fields works OK, but fields below the hidden/shown field do not reposition appropriately, and when the field is made visible again, the lower fields overlap the one that was previously hidden.
I've tried the Me.Repaint and Me.Recalc functions, but they have no effect.
I find that if I toggle between 'Form View' and 'Layout View' manually then it updates correctly.
Is there a function I can run that replicates the toggling of the 'Form View' and 'Layout View'??
Thanks
ADDITIONAL INFO 25/11
When I asked "Is there a function I can run that replicates the toggling of the 'Form View' and 'Layout View'??"  -What I meant was, is there a way to rebuild the form in the same way that switching between 'Form View' and 'Layout View' does - because .repaint and .recalc don't work as I hoped.
I'm currently using a "Stacked" layout - so when I reduce the height of a control, the layout automatically adjusts to fill the space left behind - I don't need to move all controls below it up. This "automatic adjustment" seems to work in some cases but not all (hence this post).

Probably need to use Top property instead of Height. That's what I do. Better to fix existing code than try to kludge something with toggling form views. Post your code.

Toggle views with Docmd.RunCommand acCmdFormView and
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdLayoutView. Make sure form AllowLayoutView property is set to yes.

This question is similar to: How can I change the view of an MS Access subform at runtime in VBA code?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for the comments - they help me to clarify the question. I'll edit the original question with additional information.

Could improve question title. Are controls grouped? I never do that. I move controls, not change height.

See my ModernBox at GitHub: VBA.ModernBox.
Here I in this code section hide those buttons not used and, at the bottom, shuffle the visible buttons around:
Private Sub SetButtonSequence()

' Arrange from one to four visible buttons and refresh their captions.

    ' Maximum count of enabled (visible) buttons including Help button.
    Const MaxButtonCount    As Long = 3 + 1
    ' First button index.
    Const FirstButton       As Long = 0
    ' Undefined result value for Help button and inactive buttons.
    Const MsgBoxResultNone  As Long = 0
    
    Dim WindowWidth         As Long
    Dim WindowExpand        As Long
    Dim WindowExtend        As Long
    Dim ActiveButtonCount   As Long
    Dim HelpButtonCount     As ButtonCount
    Dim ButtonIndex         As Long
    Dim LineCount           As Integer
    
    ' Fill array of localized captions.
    Call FillCaptions
    ' Fill array of button positions.
    Call FillPositions
    
    If HelpButton = vbMsgBoxHelpButton Then
        ' The Help button shall be displayed.
        HelpButtonCount = ButtonCount.Help
    End If
    
    ' Set captions and return values on active (visible) buttons.
    Select Case ButtonSequence
        Case vbAbortRetryIgnore
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.AbortRetryIgnore
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonAbort), VbMsgBoxResult.vbAbort)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 1) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonRetry), VbMsgBoxResult.vbRetry)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 2) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonIgnore), VbMsgBoxResult.vbIgnore)
            NoCancel = True
        Case vbOKCancel
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.OKCancel
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonOK), VbMsgBoxResult.vbOK)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 1) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonCancel), VbMsgBoxResult.vbCancel)
        Case vbOkOnly
            ' Note: Any click action (except Help) will result in Cancel.
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.OKOnly
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonOK), VbMsgBoxResult.vbCancel)
        Case vbRetryCancel
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.RetryCancel
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonTryAgain), VbMsgBoxResult.vbRetry)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 1) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonCancel), VbMsgBoxResult.vbCancel)
        Case vbYesNo
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.YesNo
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonYes), VbMsgBoxResult.vbYes)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 1) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonNo), VbMsgBoxResult.vbNo)
            NoCancel = True
        Case vbYesNoCancel
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.YesNoCancel
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonYes), VbMsgBoxResult.vbYes)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 1) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonNo), VbMsgBoxResult.vbNo)
            Buttons(FirstButton + 2) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonCancel), VbMsgBoxResult.vbCancel)
        Case Else
            ' Identical to OKOnly.
            ' Note: Any click action (except Help) will result in Cancel.
            ActiveButtonCount = ButtonCount.OKOnly
            Buttons(FirstButton) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonOK), VbMsgBoxResult.vbCancel)
    End Select
    
    ' Add a Help button at far right if requested.
    If HelpButtonCount = 1 Then
        HelpButtonIndex = ActiveButtonCount
        Buttons(HelpButtonIndex) = Array(True, Captions(ButtonCaption.ButtonHelp), MsgBoxResultNone)
        ActiveButtonCount = ActiveButtonCount + HelpButtonCount
    End If
    ' Reset remaining buttons.
    For ButtonIndex = ActiveButtonCount To MaxButtonCount - 1
        Buttons(ButtonIndex) = Array(False, vbNullString, MsgBoxResultNone)
    Next
    ' Set display status for all buttons.
    For ButtonIndex = FirstButton To MaxButtonCount - 1
        With Me("Button" & CStr(ButtonIndex))
            .Visible = Buttons(ButtonIndex)(ButtonProperty.Visible)
            .Caption = Buttons(ButtonIndex)(ButtonProperty.Caption)
        End With
    Next
    
    ' Expand the form to make room for multiple buttons.
    WindowExpand = Positions(ActiveButtonCount - 1) - Positions(FirstButton)
    WindowWidth = Me.WindowWidth + WindowExpand
    Me.Move Me.WindowLeft, Me.WindowTop, WindowWidth
   
    ' Remove form's close button for certain button combinations.
    If NoCancel = True Then
        Me!ButtonCancel.Enabled = False
    Else
        ' Reposition Cancel button and form's close button (picture).
        Me!ButtonCancel.Left = Me!ButtonCancel.Left + WindowExpand
        Me!PictureClose.Left = Me!PictureClose.Left + WindowExpand
        Me!PictureCloseActive.Left = Me!PictureCloseActive.Left + WindowExpand
        Me!PictureCloseInactive.Left = Me!PictureCloseInactive.Left + WindowExpand
        Me!BoxInactive.Left = Me!BoxInactive.Left + WindowExpand
    End If
    
    ' Extend the form to fit a supersized prompt.
    LineCount = PromptLineCount()
    If LineCount > 0 Then
        ' Extend the form and controls (except buttons) to
        ' make room for multiple prompt lines.
        WindowExtend = FormExtend(LineCount)
    End If
    ' Position active buttons.
    For ButtonIndex = FirstButton To ActiveButtonCount - 1
        With Me("Button" & CStr(ButtonIndex))
            .Left = Positions(ButtonIndex)
            .Top = .Top + WindowExtend
        End With
    Next
    
    ' Apply tab settings.
    Call SetDefaultButton
    
End Sub

No repaint is needed.
